# Looking for better way to handle chain of XMLHttpRequests with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a list of things to process and I update their status as I call the server-side script. I made this function call that recursively calls the script so that the calls execute sequentially avoiding any confusion about what to update, but it seems inelegant and I worry that it might eat up memory if there are too many items in the list.

Is there a better way to handle this?

multiXHR.pageToUpdate.html

```
<head>
  <title>Test Multi XHR</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var listArray = ["1","2","3","4","5"];
    var currentStatus = 0;

    function doSeveralThings(index) {
      currentStatus=index;
      status = "status" + index;
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
          if (xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById(status).innerHTML = "done";
            currentStatus++;
            if (currentStatus<listArray.length) {
              doSeveralThings(currentStatus);
            }
          } else {
            document.getElementById(status).innerHTML = "[error: " + xmlhttp.statusText + ", readyState: " + xmlhttp.readyState + ", status: " + xmlhttp.status +"]" ;
          }
        } else {
          document.getElementById(status).innerHTML = "[processing]";
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "multiXHR.doOneThing.php?thisItemNumber=" + currentStatus, true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function makeList() {
      for(index=0; index< listArray.length; index++) {
        listItemSpan = "<span>" + "&nbsp"+ index + ":&nbsp" + "<a id='status" + index + "' style='color:black'>[queued]</a></span><br>";
        document.getElementById("listToProcess").innerHTML += listItemSpan;
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    List To Process:<br />
    <span id="listToProcess"></span>
  </p>

  <p>
    Process: <button onclick="doSeveralThings(0)">Go</button>
  </p>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    makeList();
  </script>
</body>
```

multiXHR.doOneThing.php

```
<?php

  $returnVal = $_SESSION["thisItemNumber"];

  sleep(1); # pretend to do something that takes time

  echo($returnVal);

?>
```

Comment: Well you could code the server to handle multiple items...

Comment: Here's a good read on the new `window.fetch()` api:
http://techblog.ironfroggy.com/2014/10/farewell-to-xmlhttprequest-long-live.html

Comment: or addyosmani's tweet: https://twitter.com/addyosmani/status/555409536560168960

Comment: The problem with letting the server-side handle multiple items is it can't update the status on the calling page as it processes each item.

Comment: Does window.fetch have wide support? I don't see it at w3schools.